# Is the @import call supported within <style> tags?

Tags: css, import, styles

So it's not supported to have:

```
...
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
...
```

but what's the consensus with being able to do:

```
...
<body>
<style>
    @import '/custom.css';
</style>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

style tags and link rel should be within the head tags but that does not mean it won`t work inside body or divs. its just not good practice

```
 @import '/custom.css';
```

should be placed only inside css files

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have an `@import` rule at the start of a style sheet even when the style sheet appears as the content of a `style` element.

However, neither `style` nor `link` elements are allowed within `body`, only within `body`, according to the formal rules of HTML. These rules are not enforced in practice; the elements work just as they do inside `head`. (Division into `body` and `head` is really just formal.)